# How do I parse a string using C# and regular expressions?

Tags: c#, regex, string, parsing

How do I convert the string:

`"Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition|C:\\WINDOWS|\\Device\\Harddisk4\\Partition1"`

to

`"Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition"`

...using regular expressions?

I want to cut out all after `|` symbol. Is it easy to realise it via `Regex.Replace`? Where could I found syntax description for `Regex.Replace` patterns?

Comment: if all you care is the first segment, use driis' answer. if you will ever want to expand what you care about, use the Split approach.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
string str = @"Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk4\Partition1";
string str2 = str.Split('|')[0];
```

str2 = "Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition"

Comment: I assume that this is not a user-entered string. If it was a) the UI wouldn't be very usable and b) the app would probably be for personal use. For a production app you would definitely have to validate the user input.

Answer (score 13):

You don't need a Regex for that. You can use substring:

```
var text = @"Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition|C:\WINDOWS|\Device\Harddisk4\Partition1";
text = text.Substring(0,text.IndexOf("|"));
```

Comment: But just in case the text does not contain "|", then you will have an exception.
So better put it in try catch if not always sure about having "|" in the input string.

Comment: Or even better, do it in three lines, with an if check on the result of IndexOf, and avoid the exception altogether.

Comment: Correct, you should check the return value of IndexOf before using it, to make sure that the | character actually exists in the string. The code example illustrates the concept.

Answer (score 3):

If you're determined to use a regular expression:

```
Regex p = new Regex(@"([^|]*)|");
string s = @"Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition|C:\\WINDOWS|\\Device\\Harddisk4\\Partition1";
s = p.Match(s).Value;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use String.Split(), which yields a String[], then pick up element zero.

Answer (score 1):

```
string GetOSType(string data)
{
      return data.Split(Convert.ToChar("|"))[0];
}
```

this is assuming the string is ALWAYS going to split. Probably to be sure you would want to wrap a try - catch block around this function.

Comment: Couldn't you use the character constant '|' instead of calling the method Convert.ToChar("|")?

Answer (score 0):

If you still want to learn some more about Regular expressions here is a good [Cheat Sheet](http://regexlib.com/CheatSheet.aspx) and a simple online [regex builder tool](http://www.txt2re.com/index-csharp.php3) to get you started.

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution may be to use:

```
    string szOrig = "Microsoft Windows XP Professional x64 Edition|C:\\WINDOWS|\\Device\\Harddisk4\\Partition1";
    string[] separator = new string[] { "|" };
    string[] szTemp = szOrig.Split(separator, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
    string szRequired = szTemp[0];
```

May not be the best way, but works.

Comment: Agree with Botz3000 about the Hungarian. Especially since C# doesn't use zero-terminated strings, which is the sz stands for.